# CSS background using "background-size: cover" doesn't fit the full height

Tags: svg, css

I'm making a page that will just display an SVG image, and here are the requirements:

- the vector should take up the entire window
- the vector should maintain its aspect ratio (defined in the SVG file itself)
- the vector should crop/clip in order to prevent skewing

The CSS...

```
body {
  background: url(/path/to/image.svg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

...works *almost* perfectly except that when the browser window becomes too narrow it tiles instead of cropping/clipping.

Here are some screen shots (please ignore the artifacts left by dabblet):
[image: window close to aspect ratio]

Here the window is close to the aspect ratio of the original image
[image: window "shorter" than aspect ratio]

Here the window is "shorter" than the aspect ratio, and the image is cropping (as desired).
[image]

Here the window is "narrower" than the aspect ratio, but instead of cropping, the image is tiling (undesired).

Here are some thoughts that I had...

- Could I change the SVG image in some way to prevent this from happening?
- Could I markup/style the page to achieve the desired results?
- I would prefer to keep in the realm of HTML/CSS, but if Javascript is needed, then so-be-it.

Here's the dabblet that I was working with... http://dabblet.com/gist/6033198

Comment: tiling occurs automatically for backgrounds in css, just use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: @pebbl You are right, background-repeat would prevent the vector from repeating, but that doesn't fix the fact that the y dimension of the vector is not properly calculated. The image should fill the y dimension of the window.

Comment: +1 Ah, your question didn't lead me to the answer you were looking for. Might I suggest, for future searchers, that you re-title this question something like '"background-size: cover" not covering full window'. The SVG element is misleading as the same behaviour is true with images, so is the 'preventing repeatition' part. Basically your assumption was that body & html dimensions fill the entire window, which isn't always the case -- as you now know -- html & body are odd/special elements in the way they behave.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After some trial-and-error, this is what I found.

Adding (to the original CSS):

```
html {
  height: 100%
}
```

delivered exactly what I was looking for in the original spec.

Additionally, if I wanted the image to be center when it was cropped, I could use:

```
html { 
  background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Lastly, if I wanted it to be centered, always maintain the aspect ratio, but NOT be cropped (i.e., some whitespace is OK) then I could do:

```
body {
  background: url(/path/to/image.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me I had all other properties set except `background-attachment:fixed`. I had experienced the same issue on a site of mine for ages, one of the most elusive and infuriating bugs I've ever come across, but adding this to the `html` element seems to have finally solved it for me.

Comment: Solved it for me too! This should have more upvotes!

Answer (score -2):

This css is working.Thanks

```
"background-size: contain;"

.cover{background:url(images/cover.jpg) no-repeat top center; display:inline-block; width:100%; height:400px; background-size: contain;}

<div class="cover">&nbsp;</div>
```